# Dynamically create a forum and link to an entity content type

Tags: nodes

I need to be able to create a forum container and link it to a content type. I tried Node Hierarchy but it only allows forum topics, I need there to be a Forum Container as a child of the content type

Content Type -> Forum Container -> Forum -> Forum Topic

Anybody know how to go about this?